# MQ to Kafka source connector filter

Tags: java, apache-kafka, ibm-mq, apache-kafka-connect, jsonpath

I am trying to configure a Kafka source connector to read messages from IBMMQ and route those messages to a Kafka topic. I am getting 2 types of messages, and value of the both message is a string.
Eg: `AB ABC123 PQRZ 20220724 IJK BLA BLA-BLA` and
`AB PQR123 1234 20220724 IJK BLA BLA-BLA XYZ`

I want to filter out one of those messages based on the string content of the value.

If I take the above 2 messages as an example, I want the message which contains ABC123 to be produced to the Kafka topic and PQR123 to be dropped. [The examples shown in the confluent](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-confluent.html#confluent-filter) are all based on JSON payload. Is there any way I can do this without writing a custom transform class (java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write custom code, or pre-process the data using tools like Kafka Streams, ksqlDB, Flink, Spark, etc.

Kafka Connect works best on structured data, not plain strings, and even if you have JSON, there is no "String contains" filter that is built-in. The linked transform from Confluent would have to be installed separately, and you can try using `=~` JSONPath operator.

Comment: Thanks.  If I write custom code in Java, do I have to implement the `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Transformation` interface? I am struggling to understand how, as the value doesn't have a schema, how do I make it work. Do you have any examples that I can refer to? I tried with HoistField transform, but not sure if that is the correct path to solve this.

Comment: Struct/Schemas are not required for transforms, no. The Struct valueSchema would be null, or equal to String/Bytes schema, for example. The hoist transform won't help with string containment. Have you tried using the linked transform with something like `$[?(@ =~ "ABC123")]` ...? Plain strings are still valid JSON

Comment: Couldn't find much about the linked transformation. Let's say I want to write a custom transformation code to filter out the 'PQR123' records by overriding the  `https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Filter.java` class. How do I exclude the records in the R apply (R record)  method?  should I return null? Hope you got what I am trying to do here.

Comment: Yes, you can return null, or you can try `filter.type=exclude` option with `$[?(@ =~ "PQR123")]` JSONPath query in the connector you mentioned (which is in a different repo)